# findstr regex expression

Tags: regex

I am really struggling trying to get a regex expression to work with findstr.  I have the following in a text file called filelist.txt as an example....

```
test1
test12
test13
test14
uyt*
test16
test19
test47
nam;
help367
file1
named665
```

I also have a set of acceptable characters which are **A-Z, a-z, 0-9, space ./-_**

I want to run findstr and have it return all the results which contain characters that are not acceptable, in this case it should return the following....

```
**nam;
uyt***
```

I am using the following command

```
findstr /r /v "[^a-zA-Z0-9_./-]" filelist.txt
```

But this is returning the opposite of what I want, it is displaying all entries that don't have special characters in them.  I have tried substituting /v for /x to display the matches but this does not return anything.

Can anyone help???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
findstr /b /e /r /v /C:"[a-zA-Z0-9_ ./-]*" filelist.txt
```

or

```
findstr /r /x /C:".*[^a-zA-Z0-9_ ./-].*" filelist.txt
```

Comment: Tried both of those commands, neither of which return anything

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the first one returns all of the values and the second command returns no values

Comment: @ightstarr20: It appears that the space is not liked. Remove the spaces from the brackets and it will work.

Comment: perfect, that worked this time.  Any idea how to include a space?

Comment: Found it. Editing the answer.